# No Java files found which extend CordovaActivity. when use "cordova build"

Tags: java, android, cordova

My computer is Windows 8 64bit, i install cordova and android platform for my project, I have created my project by input `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` and `cordova platform add android` 
but when i run `cordova build`, it show below error:

`[Error: No Java files found which extend CordovaActivity.]`

i searched the web but didn't find the solution yet, What's the problem?

Comment: How did you install Cordova? Were you connected to the internet  when you ran the commands?  Can you try again with the `-d` flag in all of your commands and post what comes out?

Answer (score 134):

I had the same error when I cloned my repository from another project. I solved it by removing the platforms and adding it again.

remove : `cordova platform rm android`
add : `cordova platform add android`

Comment: That was a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: Experienced it after a ```cordova clean``` somehow... Anyways, this solved it and so it should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. Solved!

Comment: I encountered the issue when I updated the edit-config for manifest.xml of my ionic project. After following the answer, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 26):

All you need to do is remove platform `cordova platform rm android` and re-add platform by typing `cordova platform add android`, and the error goes away

Answer (score 19):

Typically happens when one change the id in the config.xml file after the platform was added:

```
<widget id="changed-this-id" ...
```

To fix:

```
remove : cordova platform rm android
add : cordova platform add android
```

Comment: This explanation makes it easier to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 16):

In Eclipse or another editor, go into the .java source file under platforms/android/src/ and make sure the class extends CordovaActivity (it may have previously extended DroidGap instead).

Comment: Thanks @hyperizer - you're only contribution to Stack Overflow, but it saved me!

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue when upgrading from 2.x
For example change:
`public class Your_App_Name extends DroidGap`
to:
`public class Your_App_Name extends CordovaActivity`

Comment: that is not going to work with a hybrid where you don't use the CordovaActivity.

Comment: I'm running with ionic v5, .java source file does not exist under platforms/android/src/. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue (albeit on Ubuntu) and tried Hyperizer's answer, which should have worked... but to no effect for me. Note I had the error after upgrading cordova (from 3.0.9 to 3.4.0-0.1.3), and so my generated platforms folders were out of sync with the latest cordova version.

I found the cleanest thing to do (and this worked for me) is to remove your /platforms/android directory (as per cornelius' answer... but my focus is cordova), and then recreate with cordova so you know everything is up to date and inline with the current cordova version.

```
cd platforms
rm -rf android
cd ..
cordova platform add android
```

Your android folder is recreated, and now try building and running again.

```
cordova build android
cordova emulate android
```

The downside of blowing away and recreating the android platform folder is that you will need to re-apply any customisations you may have made to the android source...(I hadn't had to thankfully) but then you should be able to pull this from your git etc. At least now you are working on a clean and tidy up to date build.

Answer (score 10):

This error happened when I change the package id name from the config.xml, such as io.cordova..etc to another package name, so I solved it by removing the platform of android and changed version info and package name from config file, and run command android cordova platform add android

Answer (score 8):

This error comes when you changed the package id or name in config.xml, All you need to do is remove the android platform by typing "**Cordova platform rm android**" and re-add the platform by typing "**Cordova platform add android**". You can get a successful build.

Answer (score 7):

The .java file with the Activity extending the CordovaActivity must be exactly in com.example.app - as specified in the config.xml's  id="com.example.app" tag.

This changed in 3.2.0 - filed a bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5515

Comment: I am having the same problem. I can't compile and when trying to use the CLI to run the app I get "No Java files found which extends cordovaactivity"  Is there a command I can run to fetch the needed files? I can't find them for download anywhere on the phonegap website.

Comment: You have the .java file already - it is in a subfolder of the /src folder of your cordova android project - search for "CordovaActivity". --> Change the package name of your activity in this java file to the id as specified in your global Cordova config.xml id tag, e.g., "com.example.app".

Comment: You can always downgrade to 2.9.1 `npm install -g phonegap@2.9.0-rc1-0.12.2`

Answer (score 6):

Just on a related topic regarding **PhoneGap 3.2** causing the same error, chances are that you probably messed up the app when configuring and trying to get it running initially

What worked for me was to remove the generated android platform files and just run the RUN command again. So from your PhoneGap project's home directory, do the following

```
cd platforms
sudo rm -rf android
cd ..
sudo phonegap local run android --emulator
```

I am working on a Macbook Pro with OSX version 10.9

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Worked for me. My problem was a missing MyApp.java file at `platforms\android\src\com\MyCom\MyApp` which was restored by removing the android platform files and rebuilding/running.

Answer (score 3):

Remove platform and add again. This worked for me:

Remove:

`cordova platform rm android`

Then add:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon a "solution" for anyone who uses a Framework that "hides" the extending of the CordovaActivity, i.e. the MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends GDCordovaActivity {...}
```

where *GDCordovaActivy* is your Framework Activity extending CordovaActivity.

Simply add a "foo.java" File to the project only containing a comment like this:

```
/** extends CordovaActivity */
```

As the cordova framework parses the file and doesn't recognize the comments you will be able to call `cordova android prepare` etc. without any errors.

Comment: ^this -- but just do it in MainActivity.java like so: public class MainActivity extends RMCActivity  /** extends CordovaActivity */ { ... }

Answer (score 2):

This issue is causing due to missing of MainActivity.Java File 
Generally it is residing on the below path.

```
[Application Name]\platforms\android\src\com
```

Here it should have the folder name based on the namespace you have given.

```
Suppose I have  given namespace as com.passion.oilfreerecipes
So there should have folder  passion --> OilfreeRecipes
```

And inside of their you should have MainActivity.Java.

It clears in my application as i clean the solution.
You can copy and paste from other project and change the mainActivity.Java based on your need.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your `id` and `android-packageName` in `config.xml` do not match.

`android-packageName="com.example.app" id="com.example.app"`

Answer (score 1):

I had too many customisations and did not want to recreate the platforms.

Solved this by changing the `widget id` in `defaults.xml` to the new package name (I changed the default `io.hellocordova` into my own package structure)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by reset the JAVA Environment.

```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

choose the number for /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

To choose a default javac compiler, run the following command.

```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

If you prefer to use a gui instead of the command line, you can execute galternatives instead and define the default versions of software with the following dialog.

```
    $ sudo galternatives
```